# Отправка формы .validate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation

Есть форма в модалке, на [сайте](http://funny.sem-dev.co.ua/)
Клик на "Оставить заявку"

Модалка реализована следующим образом.

```
//modal

    var modal = {
        self: $(".modal"),

        showModal: function(content) {
            this.self.find("#innerModal").html(content);
            this.self.fadeIn(500);
        },
        hideModal: function() {
            this.self.fadeOut(200);
            this.self.find("#innerModal").html("");
        }
    };

    //show modal
    $(".js_popUp").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var _popUp = $(this).data("popup");
        var content = $('.js-popUp' + _popUp).html();
        modal.showModal(content);
    });

    //hide modal
    modal.self.on("click", function(e) {
        if (
            $(e.target).attr("id") === "modal" ||
            $(e.target).hasClass("js-closePopup")
        ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal.hideModal();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });

<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal__wrap">
        <div id="innerModal"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ну и само окно с формой.

```
<div class="header__application">
    <h3>Оставить заявку</h3>
    <a href="#" class="header__application-close js-closePopup"></a>
    <form class="header__application-form js-applicationForm js-form" action="">
        <div>
            <span class="field-wrap">
                <p>Ваше имя</p>
                <input class="js-validate" type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name">
            </span>
            <span class="field-wrap">
                <p>Телефон</p>
                <input class="" type="tel" placeholder="+7 ____ ____ __ __" name="tel">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="field-wrap">
                <p>Комментарий</p>
                <textarea class="" rows="5" placeholder="Пожалуйста, опишите подробнее о своём празднике." name="text"></textarea>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span class="field-wrap">
                <p>Почта</p>
                <input class="" type="email" placeholder="@inbox.ru" name="email">
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="Btn_black">Отправить</button>
            <a class="js-clearApplication" href="#">Стереть</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Подключена библиотека jquery.validate

Тут инициализация. Костыль. Ибо по другому не работает в этой модалке.
Инициализирует после клика по первому инпуту.

```
$.validator.addMethod('fnType', function(value, element) {
    return value.match(/^\+(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/);
},'Введите корректный номер');


document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    var modal =  document.querySelector('#modal');
    modal.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
        var target = ev.target;

        if (target.classList.contains('js-validate')){
            $('#innerModal .header__application-form.js-applicationForm.js-form').validate({
                submitHandler: function (){
                    alert('OK!');
                    console.log('sdfgsd');
                },
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2
                    },
                    text: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 20
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    tel: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 12,
                        fnType: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: {
                        required: "Поле обязательно к заполнению",
                        minlength: "Введите не менее 2-х символов в поле"
                    },
                    text: {
                        required: "Поле обязательно к заполнению",
                        minlength: "Введите не менее 20-ти символов в поле"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Поле обязательно к заполнению",
                        email: "Введите корректный email"
                    },
                    tel: {
                        required: "Поле обязательно к заполнению",
                        minlength: "Введите не менее 12-ти символов в поле"
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Осталась проблема в том, что форма не отправляется. По клику на отправку формы alert не выводит. Ничего не работает.

Comment: 1. Попробуйте добавить кнопку type="submit". Так же ваш "костыль" не делает ничего хорошего. Лучше просто явно вызовите инициализацию скрипта валидации, в методе showModal (после вставки html)

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov Пробовал, не помогло. На странице еще 3 формы. Там все работает.

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov ок. попробую.

Comment: @PavelGorobtsov не помогло. 
Я уже переписал модалку. Валидатор инициализируется без каких либо костылей. Но отправка не идет(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в модалке. 
При закрытии оно обрывало ф-ю.

```
 modal.self.on("click", function(e) {
        if (
            $(e.target).attr("id") === "modal" ||
            $(e.target).hasClass("js-closePopup")
        ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal.hideModal();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Убрал

```
 else {
   return false;
}
```

и все заработало)